# Trying to pull from API with Ruby -- how to pass variable into string?

Tags: ruby

Im trying to practice pulling APIs with Ruby. Im trying to pull videogame news from Steam.

Below is my code.

The idea is, when the program is ran, the the user is prompted to enter a game ID between 200 and 440.

Anything not in between dont exist or the numbers arent continuous.

Anyway, Im trying to pass the gameID variable into the string:

"http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=#{gameID}&count=5&maxlength=300&format=json"

The string is wrapped in a function. When I try to run the program, the error says wrong number of arguments ( 0 for 1 ).

What am i doing wrong, and what am I missing? Many thanks in advance as usual :)

*been doing nothing but asking questions so far, hope to contribute someday once I get better :)

```
require 'json'
require 'HTTParty'

puts "----------------------------------------------------------" 
puts "Welcome to my practice"
puts "The purpose of this exercise is to use the SteamAPI"
puts "to pull videogame news from Steam"
puts "----------------------------------------------------------"

reset = true
while reset
    puts "Please enter a game ID between 200 - 440"
    gameID = gets.to_i
    if gameID < 200
        puts "--Invalid input--"
        reset = true
    elsif gameID > 400
        puts "--Invalid input--"
        reset= true
    else
        reset = false
    end
end

puts "--------------------Loading API----------------------------"

def get_news( gameID )
    string = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=#{gameID}&count=5&maxlength=300&format=json"
    page = HTTParty.get( string )
    browse = page["appnews"]["newsitems"]
    browse.map do |content|
        {title: content["title"], contents: content["contents"]}
    end
end

def display_story( content )
    puts "Title: #{content[:title]}"
    puts "--------------------" 
    puts " #{content[:contents]}"
    puts "--------------------"
end

get_news.each do |content|
    display_story( content )
end
```

Comment: Your code hurts my brain. :)  You define functions in the middle of your code, which is really weird, and then call `.each` on `get_news` which isn't anything at all...  There's a function by that name but you've done nothing to create something that is enumerable on which you might call `.each`.  You then call `display_story` with `content`, which can't be anything...  I think you meant to call `get_news(gameID).each`

Comment: `get_news` returns the result of `map`, which is plenty enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `get_news` to take a `gameID` argument, but you haven't passed it anything. At the end of your file, you need `get_news(gameID).each`.